# Tikz intersection without extending the paths till they intersect

Tags: tikz-pgf

The below MWE draws a certain isosceles triangle:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections, positioning}

\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);    
\path[name path=AC] (A)--++(80:6cm);
\path[name path=BC] (B)--++(100:6cm);
\path[name intersections={of=AC and BC, by=C}];
\draw (A)--(B)--(C)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, if the named paths are not extended long enough, for example `\path[name path=AC] (A)--++(80:1cm);` I get an error. Though this is not a problem (that one just enters an arbitrary big number), is there a way (a notation perhaps, or whatever) to tell Tikz that the paths are intersecting (even if the defined path is not long enough)?

Comment: There is a (deprecated) intersection syntax that you could use, see Ulrike's answer to https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/419504/tikz-extend-an-inclined-line/419508#419508

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax that still works for the intersection of two lines. It is no longer documented since version 3 of TikZ, but you will find its syntax in the [old manuals](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/557439/138900) version 1 and 2.

Its interest is that the intersection is found even if the segments are **not** intersecting, it is enough that the lines carrying them are not parallel.

It does **not need** any TikZ library to be used.

[image: screenshot]

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}

\begin{document}%

\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (2,0);    
\path(A)--++(80:6cm)coordinate(u);
\path(B)--++(100:6cm)coordinate(v);
%\path[name intersections={of=AC and BC, by=C}];
\draw (A)--(B)--(intersection of A--u and B--v)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, at least when the intersecting curves are lines. The idea is to use *intersection* in a *let ... in* action.  I saw this construction in AndréC answer [Drawing a circle through 3 non-collinear points](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/461161/drawing-a-circle-through-3-non-collinear-points/461194#461194).

I consider that two lines are given through a point and a vector for each---*A* and *v* for the first and *B* and *w* for the second.  We need their meeting point *C*.

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=1cm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.style={scale=.8}]
  % points and directions
  \path
  (0, 0) coordinate (A) (80:1) coordinate (v)
  (2, 0) coordinate (B) (100:1) coordinate (w);

  % intersection point
  \path let
  \p1 = (A),
  \p2 = ($(A)+(v)$),
  \p3 = (B),
  \p4 = ($(B)+(w)$),
  \p5 = (intersection of \p1--\p2 and \p3--\p4)
  in
  (\p5) coordinate (C);
  
  \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle;

  \draw[blue, very thick, ->] (A) -- +(v) node[above left] {$v$};
  \draw[blue, very thick, ->] (B) -- +(w) node[above right] {$w$};
  
  \foreach \P/\pos in {A/below left, B/below right, C/above left}{%
    \draw[fill=white] (\P) circle (1.2pt) node[\pos] {$\P$};
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]