# Drawing a circle through 3 non-collinear points

Tags: tikz-pgf

Does circle through works with 3 points:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);

    \node[draw,line width=2pt] [circle through={(A)(B)(C)}] {};

    \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
        \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I want to draw a circle through A,B and C.

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The `tkz-euclide` package has a macro to do this. The manual is written in French.

1. First, we define the circle with the macro `\tkzDefCircle`.
2. This macro returns two values that are the center recovered with the macro `\tkzGetPoint{O}`
3. and the radius that is recovered with the macro `\tkzGetLength{rayon}`.

Once this is done, we draw the circle with the macro `\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rayon pt)`

[image: cercle circonscrit]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);

%    \node[draw,line width=2pt] [circle through={(A)(B)(C)}] {};

\tkzDefCircle[circum](A,B,C)
\tkzGetPoint{O} \tkzGetLength{rayon}
\tkzDrawCircle[R](O,\rayon pt)

    \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
        \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 22):

A new node style, based on the derivation below plus the information that one can use `intersection of \p1--\p3 and \p2--\p4`, which I learned from [AndréC's nice answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/461194/121799)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}
\tikzset{circle through 3 points/.style n args={3}{%
insert path={let    \p1=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$),
                    \p2=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)$),
                    \p3=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)!1!-90:(#2)$),
                    \p4=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)!1!90:(#3)$),
                    \p5=(intersection of \p1--\p3 and \p2--\p4)
                    in },
at={(\p5)},
circle through= {(#1)}
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);
    \node[circle through 3 points={A}{B}{C},draw=blue]{};
    \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
        \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Just for fun: an analytic solution based on `calc` only. (My personal opinion, though, is that this method is more "Ti*k*Zy", i.e. closer to how the standard Ti*k*Z styles work, than the tkz-euclide macros, which are more like pstricks, which I have left behind. However, this is just a personal opinion, and might not be shared by others.)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{circle through 3 points/.style n args={3}{%
insert path={let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$),\p2=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$),
    \p3=($(#1)-(#3)$),\p4=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)$),\p5=(#1),\n1={(-(\x2*\x3) + \x3*\x4 + \y3*(-\y2 +
    \y4))/(\x3*\y1 - \x1*\y3)},\n2={veclen(\x5-\x2-\n1*\y1,\y5-\y2+\n1*\x1)} in
    ({\x2+\n1*\y1},{\y2-\n1*\x1}) circle (\n2)}
}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);
    \draw[circle through 3 points={A}{B}{C}];
    \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
        \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Note that `\n1` is a fraction, and could in principle not be well defined. If you ever encounter this case, just change the ordering, e.g. do `\draw[circle through 3 points={B}{C}{A}];` or something along those lines.)

**ADDENDUM**: Explanation of the analytic formula.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{circle through 3 points/.style n args={3}{%
insert path={let \p1=($(#1)-(#2)$),\p2=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$),
    \p3=($(#1)-(#3)$),\p4=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)$),\p5=(#1),\n1={(-(\x2*\x3) + \x3*\x4 + \y3*(-\y2 +
    \y4))/(\x3*\y1 - \x1*\y3)},\n2={veclen(\x5-\x2-\n1*\y1,\y5-\y2+\n1*\x1)} in
    ({\x2+\n1*\y1},{\y2-\n1*\x1}) circle (\n2)}
}}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,5}
{\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\sffamily]
\path[use as bounding box] (-1,-4) rectangle (6,4);
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);
    \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
        \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
    }
\ifnum\X=1
 \node[anchor=north,text width=7cm] (start) at (2.5,0){Starting point: 3 points.};
 \foreach \Y in {A,B,C}
 {\draw[-latex] (start) to[out=90,in=-90] (\Y) node[above=2pt]{\Y}; }
\fi
\ifnum\X=2
 \coordinate (auxAB) at ($ (A)!.5!(B) $);
 \coordinate (auxBC) at ($ (B)!.5!(C) $);
 \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
 \draw ($ (auxAB)!1.2cm!90:(B) $) -- ($ (auxAB)!1.2cm!-90:(B) $) coordinate(aux1);
 \draw ($ (auxBC)!1.2cm!90:(B) $) coordinate(aux2) -- ($ (auxBC)!1.2cm!-90:(B) $);
 \node[anchor=north,text width=7cm] (int) at (2.5,0){The center of the circle is
 where the lines that run through and are orthogonal to the edges intersect.};
 \draw[-latex] (int) to[out=45,in=-90] (aux1);
 \draw[-latex] (int) to[out=135,in=-90] (aux2);
\fi
\ifnum\X=3
 \coordinate[label=below:$P_2$] (auxAB) at ($ (A)!.5!(B) $);
 \coordinate[label=below:$P_4$] (auxBC) at ($ (B)!.5!(C) $);
 \foreach \Y in {auxAB,auxBC}
 {\fill (\Y) circle (1pt);}
 \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
 \draw ($ (auxAB)!1.2cm!90:(B) $) -- ($ (auxAB)!1.2cm!-90:(B) $);
 \draw ($ (auxBC)!1.2cm!90:(B) $) -- ($ (auxBC)!1.2cm!-90:(B) $);
 \node[anchor=north,text width=7cm] (int) at (2.5,0){Call the points in the
 middle $P_2$ and $P_4$, and the differences $P_1=A-B$ and $P_3=B-C$. Then the
 orthogonal lines will fulfill
 \[\gamma_1(\alpha)~=~\left(\begin{array}{c}
 x_2+\alpha\,y_1\\ 
 y_2-\alpha\,x_1\\ 
 \end{array}\right) \]
 and
 \[\gamma_2(\beta)~=~\left(\begin{array}{c}
 x_4+\beta\,y_3\\ 
 y_4-\beta\,x_3\\ 
 \end{array}\right)\;. \]
 };
\fi
\ifnum\X=4
 \coordinate[label=below:$P_2$] (auxAB) at ($ (A)!.5!(B) $);
 \coordinate[label=below:$P_4$] (auxBC) at ($ (B)!.5!(C) $);
 \foreach \Y in {auxAB,auxBC}
 {\fill (\Y) circle (1pt);}
 \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C);
 \draw ($ (auxAB)!1.2cm!90:(B) $) -- ($ (auxAB)!1.2cm!-90:(B) $);
 \draw ($ (auxBC)!1.2cm!90:(B) $) -- ($ (auxBC)!1.2cm!-90:(B) $);
 \node[anchor=north,text width=7cm] (int) at (2.5,0){The center of the circle is
 then simply determined by 
 \[\gamma_1(\alpha)~=~\gamma_2(\beta)\;, \]
 which has the solution
 \[
 \alpha~=~\frac{-(x_2\cdot x_3) + x_3\cdot x_4 + y_3\cdot (y_4-y_2 )}{x_3\cdot y_1 - x_1\cdot y_3}\;.
 \]
 This is \texttt{\textbackslash n1} in the Ti\emph{k}Z style \texttt{circle through 3 points}.
 };
\fi
\ifnum\X=5  
\draw[circle through 3 points={A}{B}{C}];
 \node[anchor=north,text width=7cm] (int) at (2.5,-0.1){Once we have the center,
 determining the radius (\texttt{\textbackslash n2}) is trivial, and we can draw
 the circle with a simple \texttt{insert path}.};
\fi
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) Give the analytical expression also, if possible :)

Comment: @nidhin It is in the code, isn't it?

Comment: Yes it is there. I meant outside the code. Mathematical expression.

Comment: @nidhin Done. There is a simple animation that you can create with `convert -delay 800 -loop 0 -density 300 -alpha remove <pdf> <gif>`, where `pdf` is the pdf file that gets created if you compile the lower code, and `gif` the name of the animated gif you will create.

Comment: Wow. That was more than expected. :)

Comment: @marmot (1) The first solution gives `cannot dive by zero error` when one of the coordinates is (0,0) (For example: (A) at (0,0), (B) at (1,1), (C) at (2,2).

(2) I get `dimensions too large error` with the second one. For example (8,0), (8,5), (13,5).

Comment: @blackened If the coordinates line up, as is the case for `(A)` at `(0,0)`, `(B)` at `(1,1)`, `(C)` at `(2,2)`, one cannot circle through them. (The circle would have an infinite radius.) As for your second observation: this is true, and I would like to argue that the first one is much better. (Will look at your other comment very soon.)

Comment: @marmot How does one extract the origin of the circle drawn by your first method?

Comment: @blackened This method creates a node of circle shape, and the center can be extracted with `<node>.center`, e.g. `\node[circle through 3 points={A}{B}{C},draw=blue] (n){};
 \draw[latex-] (n.center) -- ++ (-30:1);`

Comment: @marmot How can I draw a circle passing through point `A, B, C` and centre `I ` where 
`\coordinate (A) at (0,0,0);
\coordinate (C) at (7,0,0);
\coordinate (B) at  ({65/14},{15*sqrt(3)/14},0);
\coordinate (I) at  (7/2,{-7*sqrt(3)/6},0) ;`
I want circle present as an elip.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Could you please ask a new question for that? The above code can not be generalized easily to ellipses easily, nor can any code found in the answers to this question. (P.S. storing the 3d components of coordinates is extremely difficult because the user may do coordinate transformations. One would thus have to define a reference frame and define the 3d coordinates w.r.t. this frame. But LaTeX is not made for inverting 3d transformations. So in the end one may want to go with https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/176241/121799 instead.)

Comment: @marmot I have just post a question at here 

https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/478822/how-to-draw-dashed-arc-of-a-circle-behind-pyramid

Answer (score 9):

Just for fun with @AndréC's answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);

    \draw let \p1=($(A)!0.5!(B)$),
    \p2=($(A)!0.5!(C)$),
    \p3=($(\p1)!2!-90:(B)$),
    \p4=($(\p1)!2!90:(B)$),
    \p5=($(\p2)!2!-90:(C)$),
    \p6=($(\p2)!2!90:(C)$),
    \p7=(intersection of \p3--\p4 and \p5--\p6)
    in
    (A) -- (B)
    (A) -- (C)
    (\p3) -- (\p4)
    (\p5) -- (\p6)
    foreach \j in {1,...,7} {
        node[circle,minimum size=2pt,fill=red,inner sep=0,label=\j] at(\p\j) {}
    }
    node[draw,line  width=1pt,circle through= {(A)}] at (\p7)  {};

\foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
    \node[circle,minimum size=5pt,fill=red,inner sep=0,label=\i] at(\i) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

You can use `tkz-euclide` like this:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);

     \node[draw,line width=2pt] [circle through={(A)(B)(C)}] {};

    \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
        \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
    }
   \tkzCircumCenter(A,B,C)\tkzGetPoint{O}
   \tkzDrawCircle(O,A)
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Modified from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/16024/8650)
[image: Circles]

If you chose to use `tkz-euclide`, then you should consider to do all of your drawing with it - depending on what it is - you can e.g. define your points with `\tkzDefPoint(x,y)`.

Answer (score 8):

Just for comparison purpose.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}  
\usepackage{pst-eucl}
\begin{document}
\foreach \i in {1.0,1.2,...,4.0}{
\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \pstTriangle(4;30){A}(4;90){B}(\i;-45){C}
    \pstCircleABC{A}{B}{C}{O}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Just for fun, another solution inspired by the @marmot solution that calculates the intersection of two defined perpendicular bisector with the `calc` library.

[image: cercle]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,through}
\tikzset{circle through 3 points/.style n args={3}{%
insert path={let    \p1=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)$),
                    \p2=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)$),
                    \p3=($(#1)!0.5!(#2)!1!-90:(#2)$),
                    \p4=($(#1)!0.5!(#3)!1!90:(#3)$),
                    \p5=(intersection of \p1--\p3 and \p2--\p4)
                    in
                 node at (\p5) [draw,line  width=2pt,circle through= {(#1)}]{}}
}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);
    \draw[circle through 3 points={A}{B}{C}];
    \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
        \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know that one could use `\p1` etc. in `intersection of \p1--\p3 and \p2--\p4`. (I guess it will be more elegant if you manage to eliminate `draw,line  width=2pt,` from the node since `\path[circle through 3 points={A}{B}{C}];` also draws the path, which is not what `\path` usually does.

Comment: @marmot It is simple to delete `line width=2pt` which is a given parameter of the lucky1928 question. On the other hand, it is more difficult to delete `draw`. To do that, you have to find a way to pass the parameters to the node, I'll get down to work and explore (finally!) the `key handlers`. I just saw that you succeeded! Congratulations!

Comment: I really could only do that after I learned the  `intersection of \p1--\p3 and \p2--\p4` thing from you, which is much better than the analytic computation of the intersection point, and presumably also more stable (even though the analytic derivation was fun ;-). Thanks a lot! (My aim was to create a style that behaves the same way as `circle through`, which your observation made possible, so thanks again!)

Comment: @marmot Thank you very much and I have to return the compliment because it is by adapting your solution that I learned how to use `insert path` and that I am finally motivated to learn `key handlers`.

Comment: I really like that you acknowledge other posts (and I try to do the same). I wish all users would do that.... ;-)

Answer (score 7):

The code

```
\node [draw] at (1,1) [circle through={(A)}] {};
```

draw a circle whose center is at `(1,1)` and passes through `A`. In this case the center of the *Circumscribed circle* has to be calculated before using `through`.

I just used the [Straightedge and compass construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Straightedge_and_compass_construction) to calculate the center and then drew circle. The basic idea is that all the perpendicular bisectors of the edges of a triangle meet at the same point: the *circumcenter*.

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{through,intersections}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (1,1);
    \coordinate (B) at (2,2);
    \coordinate (C) at (3,1.5);
    \path[name path=c1] (A) circle[radius=5cm];
    \path[name path=c2] (B) circle[radius=5cm];
    \path[name path=c3] (C) circle[radius=5cm];
    \path[name intersections={of = c1 and c2}];
    \path[name path=o1] (intersection-1)--(intersection-2);
    \path[name intersections={of = c2 and c3}];
    \path[name path=o2] (intersection-1)--(intersection-2);
    \path[name intersections={of = o1 and o2}];
    \node[draw,line width=2pt] at (intersection-1) [circle through={(A)}]{};

        \foreach \i in {A,B,C} {
           \node[circle,minimum size=1pt,fill=red] at(\i) {};
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```