# Draw circle passing through three points in space

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-3dplot

Based on the question at here 
[How can I draw a circle knowing center and radius lies on a plane?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481922/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-knowing-center-and-radius-lies-on-a-plane)

I tried to draw the circle passing through `A, H, K`. 
[image]

I can not the result when I in put the line

```
\draw[blue,thick,circle in plane with normal={{\mynormal} with radius {\RAHK} around (I')}];
```

How can I get the result?

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz,12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds,angles} 
\usepackage{tkz-euclide,amsmath} 
\usetkzobj{all} 
\usepackage{pgfplots} 
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\makeatletter 
        \newcounter{smuggle} 
        \DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{% 
            \stepcounter{smuggle}% 
            \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1% 
            \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname 
        } 
        \DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{% 
            \smuggleone{#2}% 
            \ifnum#1>1 
            \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2% 
            \fi 
        } 
        \makeatother 
        \def\parsecoord(#1,#2,#3)>(#4,#5,#6){% 
            \def#4{#1}% 
            \def#5{#2}% 
            \def#6{#3}% 
            \smuggle{#4}% 
            \smuggle{#5}% 
            \smuggle{#6}% 
        } 
        \def\SPTD(#1,#2,#3).(#4,#5,#6){((#1)*(#4)+1*(#2)*(#5)+1*(#3)*(#6))} 
        \def\VPTD(#1,#2,#3)x(#4,#5,#6){((#2)*(#6)-1*(#3)*(#5),(#3)*(#4)-1*(#1)*(#6),(#1)*(#5)-1*(#2)*(#4))} 
        \def\VecMinus(#1,#2,#3)-(#4,#5,#6){(#1-1*(#4),#2-1*(#5),#3-1*(#6))} 
        \def\VecAdd(#1,#2,#3)+(#4,#5,#6){(#1+1*(#4),#2+1*(#5),#3+1*(#6))} 
        \newcommand{\RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal}[5]{%\typeout{N=(#1,#2,#3)}
            \foreach \XS in {1,-1}
            {\foreach \YS in {1,-1}
                {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mybeta}{\XS*acos(#3)} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{\YS*acos(#1/sin(\mybeta))} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ntest}{abs(cos(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#1)%
                        +abs(sin(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#2)+abs(cos(\mybeta)-#3)}
                    \ifdim\ntest pt<0.1pt
                    \xdef#4{\myalpha}   
                    \xdef#5{\mybeta}
                    \fi
            }}
        } 
        \tikzset{circle in plane with normal/.style args={#1 with radius #2 around #3}{ 
                /utils/exec={\edef\temp{\noexpand\parsecoord#1>(\noexpand\myNx,\noexpand\myNy,\noexpand\myNz)} 
                    \temp 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNx}{\myNx} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNy}{\myNy} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNz}{\myNz} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNormalization}{sqrt(pow(\myNx,2)+pow(\myNy,2)+pow(\myNz,2))} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNx}{\myNx/\myNormalization} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNy}{\myNy/\myNormalization} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNz}{\myNz/\myNormalization} 
                    % compute the rotation angles that transform us in the corresponding plabe 
                    \RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal{\myNx}{\myNy}{\myNz}{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta} 
                    %\typeout{N=(\myNx,\myNy,\myNz),alpha=\tmpalpha,beta=\tmpbeta,r=#2,#3} 
                    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta}{0}}, 
                insert path={[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape] 
                    #3 circle[radius=#2]} 
        }} 

    \tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.south west)rectangle 
                (current bounding box.north east)} }}
\begin{document} 
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{90}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{5} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\R{1/2*\a} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\h{\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{-30} 
    \def\r{1/2*\a}
\pgfmathsetmacro\RAHK{1/2*sqrt(\h^2*\a^2/(\a^2+\h^2))}

\pgfmathsetmacro\RBHKC{sqrt((4*sin(\angB)*\R*\a^3-4*\h^2*sin(\angB)*\R*\a+4*\R^2*\a^2+4*\R^2*\h^2+\a^4+\a^2*\h^2)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a^2+4*\h^2))} 

\typeout{\RAHK,\RBHKC} 
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0) ; 
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\a,0);
    \coordinate (B) at ({ \R*cos(\angB)}, {\a/2 + \R*sin(\angB)},0); 

    \coordinate (S) at (0,0,\h); 
    \coordinate (O) at ($ (A)!0.5!(C) $);
    \coordinate (H) at ({4*\h*\h*\R*cos(\angB)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {2*\h*\h*(2*\R*sin(\angB)+\a)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {\h*(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a)/(4*\R*\R+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)});
    \coordinate (K) at (0, {\h*\h*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)}, {\h*\a*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)});

    \coordinate (I') at ($(K)!0.5!(A) $); 
    \coordinate (I) at ($(C)!0.5!(H) $);

\foreach \v/\position in { B/below,C/right,A/left,S/above,K/above,H/right,O/below} {\draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.3pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$}; 
    } 

    \draw[thick] (S) -- (A) (S) -- (B) (S) -- (C)   (A) -- (B) -- (C) (A) --  (H) --  (K) ; 
    \draw[dashed]  (A)   -- (K) (A)   --(C) ; 

    \parsecoord(0,0,0)>(\myAx,\myAy,\myAz) 
    \parsecoord({4*\h*\h*\R*cos(\angB)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {2*\h*\h*(2*\R*sin(\angB)+\a)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {\h*(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a)/(4*\R*\R+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)})>(\myHx,\myHy,\myHz)
    \parsecoord(0, {\h*\h*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)}, {\h*\a*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)})>(\myKx,\myKy,\myKz)

    \def\mynormal{\VPTD({\myHx-\myAx},{\myHy-\myAy},{\myHz-\myAz})x({\myKx-\myAx},{\myKy-\myAy},{\myKz-\myAz})} 
    \edef\temp{\noexpand\parsecoord\mynormal>(\noexpand\myNx,\noexpand\myNy,\noexpand\myNz)} 
    \draw[blue,thick,circle in plane with normal={{\mynormal} with radius {\RAHK} around (I')}];    

    \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems are caused by the extra `{` and `}` you have in

```
\parsecoord({4*\h*\h*\R*cos(\angB)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {2*\h*\h*(2*\R*sin(\angB)+\a)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {\h*(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a)/(4*\R*\R+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)})>(\myHx,\myHy,\myHz)
\parsecoord(0, {\h*\h*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)}, {\h*\a*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)})>(\myKx,\myKy,\myKz)
```

If you remove them, you get

```
\documentclass[border=1mm,tikz,12pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{fouriernc} 
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot} 
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,angles} 
\makeatletter 
        \newcounter{smuggle} 
        \DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{% 
            \stepcounter{smuggle}% 
            \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1% 
            \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname 
        } 
        \DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{% 
            \smuggleone{#2}% 
            \ifnum#1>1 
            \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2% 
            \fi 
        } 
        \makeatother 
        \def\parsecoord(#1,#2,#3)>(#4,#5,#6){% 
            \def#4{#1}% 
            \def#5{#2}% 
            \def#6{#3}% 
            \smuggle{#4}% 
            \smuggle{#5}% 
            \smuggle{#6}% 
        } 
        \def\SPTD(#1,#2,#3).(#4,#5,#6){((#1)*(#4)+1*(#2)*(#5)+1*(#3)*(#6))} 
        \def\VPTD(#1,#2,#3)x(#4,#5,#6){((#2)*(#6)-1*(#3)*(#5),(#3)*(#4)-1*(#1)*(#6),(#1)*(#5)-1*(#2)*(#4))} 
        \def\VecMinus(#1,#2,#3)-(#4,#5,#6){(#1-1*(#4),#2-1*(#5),#3-1*(#6))} 
        \def\VecAdd(#1,#2,#3)+(#4,#5,#6){(#1+1*(#4),#2+1*(#5),#3+1*(#6))} 
        \newcommand{\RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal}[5]{%\typeout{N=(#1,#2,#3)}
            \foreach \XS in {1,-1}
            {\foreach \YS in {1,-1}
                {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mybeta}{\XS*acos(#3)} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{\YS*acos(#1/sin(\mybeta))} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ntest}{abs(cos(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#1)%
                        +abs(sin(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#2)+abs(cos(\mybeta)-#3)}
                    \ifdim\ntest pt<0.1pt
                    \xdef#4{\myalpha}   
                    \xdef#5{\mybeta}
                    \fi
            }}
        } 
        \tikzset{circle in plane with normal/.style args={#1 with radius #2 around #3}{ 
                /utils/exec={\edef\temp{\noexpand\parsecoord#1>(\noexpand\myNx,\noexpand\myNy,\noexpand\myNz)} 
                    \temp 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNx}{\myNx} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNy}{\myNy} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNz}{\myNz} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNormalization}{sqrt(pow(\myNx,2)+pow(\myNy,2)+pow(\myNz,2))} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNx}{\myNx/\myNormalization} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNy}{\myNy/\myNormalization} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNz}{\myNz/\myNormalization} 
                    % compute the rotation angles that transform us in the corresponding plabe 
                    \RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal{\myNx}{\myNy}{\myNz}{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta} 
                    %\typeout{N=(\myNx,\myNy,\myNz),alpha=\tmpalpha,beta=\tmpbeta,r=#2,#3} 
                    \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta}{0}}, 
                insert path={[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape] 
                    #3 circle[radius=#2]} 
        }} 

    \tikzset{reverseclip/.style={insert path={(current bounding box.south west)rectangle 
                (current bounding box.north east)} }}
\begin{document} 
    \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{90}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tdplot_main_coords,scale=1,line cap=butt,line join=round]
    \pgfmathsetmacro\a{5} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\R{1/2*\a} 
    \pgfmathsetmacro\h{\a}
    \pgfmathsetmacro\angB{-30} 
    \def\r{1/2*\a}
\pgfmathsetmacro\RAHK{1/2*sqrt(\h^2*\a^2/(\a^2+\h^2))}

\pgfmathsetmacro\RBHKC{sqrt((4*sin(\angB)*\R*\a^3-4*\h^2*sin(\angB)*\R*\a+4*\R^2*\a^2+4*\R^2*\h^2+\a^4+\a^2*\h^2)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a^2+4*\h^2))} 

%\typeout{\RAHK,\RBHKC} 
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0,0) ; 
    \coordinate (C) at (0,\a,0);
    \coordinate (B) at ({ \R*cos(\angB)}, {\a/2 + \R*sin(\angB)},0); 

    \coordinate (S) at (0,0,\h); 
    \coordinate (O) at ($ (A)!0.5!(C) $);
    \coordinate (H) at ({4*\h*\h*\R*cos(\angB)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {2*\h*\h*(2*\R*sin(\angB)+\a)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)}, {\h*(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a)/(4*\R*\R+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h)});
    \coordinate (K) at (0, {\h*\h*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)}, {\h*\a*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h)});

    \coordinate (I') at ($(K)!0.5!(A) $); 
    \coordinate (I) at ($(C)!0.5!(H) $);

\foreach \v/\position in { B/below,C/right,A/left,S/above,K/above,H/right,O/below} {\draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.3pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$}; 
    } 

    \draw[thick] (S) -- (A) (S) -- (B) (S) -- (C)   (A) -- (B) -- (C) (A) --  (H) --  (K) ; 
    \draw[dashed]  (A)   -- (K) (A)   --(C) ; 

    \parsecoord(0,0,0)>(\myAx,\myAy,\myAz) 
    \parsecoord(4*\h*\h*\R*cos(\angB)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h), 2*\h*\h*(2*\R*sin(\angB)+\a)/(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h), \h*(4*\R^2+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a)/(4*\R*\R+4*\a*\R*sin(\angB)+\a*\a+4*\h*\h))>(\myHx,\myHy,\myHz)
    \parsecoord(0, \h*\h*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h), \h*\a*\a/(\a*\a+\h*\h))>(\myKx,\myKy,\myKz)

    \def\mynormal{\VPTD({\myHx-\myAx},{\myHy-\myAy},{\myHz-\myAz})x({\myKx-\myAx},{\myKy-\myAy},{\myKz-\myAz})} 
    \draw[blue,thick,circle in plane with normal={{\mynormal} with radius {\RAHK} around (I')}];    

    \end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]