# Where is wrong in my code when drawing circle SAD and how to draw dasded line this circle?

Tags: tikz-3dplot

Based the answer at here, [How can I draw a circle knowing center and radius lies on a plane?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/481922/how-can-i-draw-a-circle-knowing-center-and-radius-lies-on-a-plane?fbclid=IwAR1nb0SGZrLLNoZXmyNpxM2fTbHgJnSS2eAIqmZOe8vVReevHpVsaljkQtA) I am trying to draw the circle `SAD`.Where is wrong in my code when drawing circle SAD and how to draw dasded line this circle?

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
% retrieves the 3D coordinates
\def\RawCoord(#1){\csname tikz@dcl@coord@#1\endcsname}%
\def\scalprod#1=#2.#3;{%
    \edef\coordA{\RawCoord#2}%
    \edef\coordB{\RawCoord#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfutil@tmpa{scalarproduct({\coordA},{\coordB})}
    \edef#1{\pgfutil@tmpa}}%
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\spaux}[6]{(#1)*(#4)+(#2)*(#5)+(#3)*(#6)}  
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{scalarproduct}{2}{% scalar product of two 3-vectors
    \begingroup%
    \pgfmathparse{\spaux#1#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}  

\usetikzlibrary{3d} 
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\makeatletter 
\newcounter{smuggle} 
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggleone[1]{% 
    \stepcounter{smuggle}% 
    \expandafter\global\expandafter\let\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname#1% 
    \aftergroup\let\aftergroup#1\expandafter\aftergroup\csname smuggle@\arabic{smuggle}\endcsname 
} 
\DeclareRobustCommand\smuggle[2][1]{% 
    \smuggleone{#2}% 
    \ifnum#1>1 
    \aftergroup\smuggle\aftergroup[\expandafter\aftergroup\the\numexpr#1-1\aftergroup]\aftergroup#2% 
    \fi 
} 
\makeatother 
\def\parsecoord(#1,#2,#3)>(#4,#5,#6){% 
    \def#4{#1}% 
    \def#5{#2}% 
    \def#6{#3}% 
    \smuggle{#4}% 
    \smuggle{#5}% 
    \smuggle{#6}% 
} 
\def\SPTD(#1,#2,#3).(#4,#5,#6){((#1)*(#4)+1*(#2)*(#5)+1*(#3)*(#6))} 
\def\VPTD(#1,#2,#3)x(#4,#5,#6){((#2)*(#6)-1*(#3)*(#5),(#3)*(#4)-1*(#1)*(#6),(#1)*(#5)-1*(#2)*(#4))} 
\def\VecMinus(#1,#2,#3)-(#4,#5,#6){(#1-1*(#4),#2-1*(#5),#3-1*(#6))} 
\def\VecAdd(#1,#2,#3)+(#4,#5,#6){(#1+1*(#4),#2+1*(#5),#3+1*(#6))} 
\newcommand{\RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal}[5]{%\typeout{N=(#1,#2,#3)}
    \foreach \XS in {1,-1}
    {\foreach \YS in {1,-1}
        {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mybeta}{\XS*acos(#3)} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{\YS*acos(#1/sin(\mybeta))} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\ntest}{abs(cos(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#1)%
                +abs(sin(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#2)+abs(cos(\mybeta)-#3)}
            \ifdim\ntest pt<0.1pt
            \xdef#4{\myalpha}   
            \xdef#5{\mybeta}
            \fi
    }}
} 
\tikzset{circle in plane with normal/.style args={#1 with radius #2 around #3}{ 
        /utils/exec={\edef\temp{\noexpand\parsecoord#1>(\noexpand\myNx,\noexpand\myNy,\noexpand\myNz)} 
            \temp 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNx}{\myNx} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNy}{\myNy} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNz}{\myNz} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNormalization}{sqrt(pow(\myNx,2)+pow(\myNy,2)+pow(\myNz,2))} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNx}{\myNx/\myNormalization} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNy}{\myNy/\myNormalization} 
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNz}{\myNz/\myNormalization} 
            % compute the rotation angles that transform us in the corresponding plabe 
            \RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal{\myNx}{\myNy}{\myNz}{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta} 
            %\typeout{N=(\myNx,\myNy,\myNz),alpha=\tmpalpha,beta=\tmpbeta,r=#2,#3} 
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta}{0}}, 
        insert path={[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape] 
            #3 circle[radius=#2]} 
}} 


\begin{document}
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=2;r=sqrt(3);
        alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=\ph+asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        alpha2(\th,\ph,\b)=-180+\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        beta1(\th,\ph,\a)=90+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
        beta2(\th,\ph,\a)=270+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
    }]


     \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (-3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (A)
         (3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (B)
        (0, {sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (C)
        (-3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 2) coordinate (S)
          (0,0,0)  coordinate (I)
       (0, 0,1)  coordinate (T)
       (0,0,1) coordinate(Z)
      (3/2, {(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (D);
       \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
       \draw[thick] (T) circle (R);
       \end{scope}

       \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={0}]
       \draw[dashed] (O) circle (r);
       \scalprod\myz=(T).(Z); % z component of T
       \pgfmathsetmacro{\myel}{atan(-1*\myz/r)}
       \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) 
       arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}: 
       {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) ;
       \end{scope}
       \begin{scope}[on background layer]
       \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below,C/below,S/right,D/below} {
        \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2/2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
       }
       \end{scope}
       \foreach \X in {A,B,C,O} \draw[dashed] (\X) -- (S); 
       \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle (A) -- (D) -- (S);


       % % store the coordinates of S, A and D in marcros 
       \parsecoord(-3/2, {-1/2*sqrt(3)}, 2)>(\mySx,\mySy,\mySz) 
       \parsecoord(-3/2, {-1/2*sqrt(3)}, 0)>(\myAx,\myAy,\myAz) 
       \parsecoord(3/2, {(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)>(\myDx,\myDy,\myDz) 

       \def\mynormal{\VPTD({\mySx-\myAx},{\mySy-\myAy},{\mySz-\myAz})x({\myDx-\myAx},{\myDy-\myAy},{\myDz-\myAz})} 
       \edef\temp{\noexpand\parsecoord\mynormal>(\noexpand\myNx,\noexpand\myNy,\noexpand\myNz)} 
       \draw[red,thick,circle in plane with normal={{\mynormal} with radius {R} around (T)}];
       \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: There are some brackets missing and you never execute `\temp` after saying `\edef\temp{...}`. But really I strongly recommend switching to the less clumsy way of doing this, as in my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The style `circle in plane with normal` and some of the macros used by this style were written before it was commonly known that one can retrieve 3d coordinates, which you are also using here. It is hence time for an update. So I did not even attempt to check where your code fails, but slightly modified the `circle in plane with normal` to become more convenient to use. No more `\edef\temp{...}`. The computation of the normal boils down to

```
\lincomb(S-A)=1*(S)+(-1)*(A);
\lincomb(S-D)=1*(S)+(-1)*(D);
\vecprod(nSAD)=(S-A)x(S-D);
```

where the first two lines build the linear combinations `S-A` and `S-D`, respectively, and the third line computes their vector product, i.e. the normal on the plane that runs through `S`, `A` and `D`. After that you only need to say

```
\draw[red,thick,circle in plane with normal={(nSAD) with radius {R} around (T)}];
```

Full MWE and result:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
% retrieves the 3D coordinates
\long\def\RawCoord(#1){\csname tikz@dcl@coord@#1\endcsname}%
\def\scalprod#1=#2.#3;{%
    \edef\coordA{\RawCoord#2}%
    \edef\coordB{\RawCoord#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfutil@tmpa{scalarproduct({\coordA},{\coordB})}
    \edef#1{\pgfutil@tmpa}}%
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\spaux}[6]{(#1)*(#4)+(#2)*(#5)+(#3)*(#6)}  
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{scalarproduct}{2}{% scalar product of two 3-vectors
    \begingroup%
    \pgfmathparse{\spaux#1#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}  
% projections
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{xcomp3}{3}{% x component of a 3-vector
\begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ycomp3}{3}{% y component of a 3-vector
\begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}  
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{zcomp3}{3}{% z component of a 3-vector
\begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{#3}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
% allows us to do linear combinations
\def\lincomb#1=#2*#3+#4*#5;{%
\path[overlay] let \p1=#3,\p2=#5 in 
({(#2)*(xcomp3\coord1)+(#4)*(xcomp3\coord2)},%
 {(#2)*(ycomp3\coord1)+(#4)*(ycomp3\coord2)},%
 {(#2)*(zcomp3\coord1)+(#4)*(zcomp3\coord2)}) coordinate #1;}
% vector product
\def\vecprod#1=#2x#3;{%
\path[overlay] let \p1=#2,\p2=#3 in 
 ({vpx({\coord1},{\coord2})},%
 {vpy({\coord1},{\coord2})},%
 {vpz({\coord1},{\coord2})}) coordinate #1;}
% vector product auxiliary functions
\newcommand{\vpauxx}[6]{(#2)*(#6)-(#3)*(#5)}     
\newcommand{\vpauxy}[6]{(#4)*(#3)-(#1)*(#6)}
\newcommand{\vpauxz}[6]{(#1)*(#5)-(#2)*(#4)}
% vector product pgf functions
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vpx}{2}{% x component of vector product
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{\vpauxx#1#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vpy}{2}{% y component of vector product
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{\vpauxy#1#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vpz}{2}{% z component of vector product
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{\vpauxz#1#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\newcommand{\RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal}[5]{%\typeout{N=(#1,#2,#3)}
            \foreach \XS in {1,-1}
            {\foreach \YS in {1,-1}
                {\pgfmathsetmacro{\mybeta}{\XS*acos(#3)} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myalpha}{\YS*acos(#1/sin(\mybeta))} 
                    \pgfmathsetmacro{\ntest}{abs(cos(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#1)%
                        +abs(sin(\myalpha)*sin(\mybeta)-#2)+abs(cos(\mybeta)-#3)}
                    \ifdim\ntest pt<0.1pt
                    \xdef#4{\myalpha}   
                    \xdef#5{\mybeta}
                    \fi
            }}
        } 
\tikzset{circle in plane with normal/.style args={#1 with radius #2 around #3}{ 
        /utils/exec={\scalprod\myn=#1.#1;
            \lincomb(normalizednormal)=(1/sqrt(\myn))*#1+0*#1;
            \edef\coordn{\RawCoord(normalizednormal)}%
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNx}{xcomp3\coordn}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNy}{ycomp3\coordn}
            \pgfmathsetmacro{\myNz}{zcomp3\coordn}      
            % compute the rotation angles that transform us in the corresponding plabe 
            \RotationAnglesForPlaneWithNormal{\myNx}{\myNy}{\myNz}{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta} 
            %\typeout{N=(\myNx,\myNy,\myNz),alpha=\tmpalpha,beta=\tmpbeta,r=#2,#3} 
            \tdplotsetrotatedcoords{\tmpalpha}{\tmpbeta}{0}}, 
        insert path={[tdplot_rotated_coords,canvas is xy plane at z=0,transform shape] 
            #3 circle[radius=#2]} 
}}      
\begin{document}
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=2;r=sqrt(3);
        alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=\ph+asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        alpha2(\th,\ph,\b)=-180+\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        beta1(\th,\ph,\a)=90+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
        beta2(\th,\ph,\a)=270+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
    }]
    \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (-3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (A)
         (3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (B)
        (0, {sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (C)
        (-3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 2) coordinate (S)
          (0,0,0)  coordinate (I)
       (0, 0,1)  coordinate (T)
       (0,0,1) coordinate(Z)
      (3/2, {(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (D);
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={0}]
    \draw[dashed] (O) circle (r);
    \scalprod\myz=(T).(Z); % z component of T
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myel}{atan(-1*\myz/r)}
    \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) 
    arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}: 
    {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below,C/below,S/right,D/below} {
      \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2/2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
     }
    \end{scope}
    \draw[dashed] foreach \X in {A,B,C,O} {(\X) -- (S)}; 
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle (A) -- (D) -- (S);
    %
    \lincomb(S-A)=1*(S)+(-1)*(A);
    \lincomb(S-D)=1*(S)+(-1)*(D);
    \vecprod(nSAD)=(S-A)x(S-D);
    \draw[red,thick,circle in plane with normal={(nSAD) with radius {R} around (T)}];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, in your setup the normal has a vanishing z component, i.e. the plane is only an xz plane rotated by an angle that can be computed from the x and y components of the normal. You can thus distinguish between the visible and hidden stretches using the functions `beta1` and `beta2`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm, 12 pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-3dplot}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter
% retrieves the 3D coordinates
\long\def\RawCoord(#1){\csname tikz@dcl@coord@#1\endcsname}%
\def\scalprod#1=#2.#3;{%
    \edef\coordA{\RawCoord#2}%
    \edef\coordB{\RawCoord#3}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro\pgfutil@tmpa{scalarproduct({\coordA},{\coordB})}
    \edef#1{\pgfutil@tmpa}}%
\makeatother 
\newcommand{\spaux}[6]{(#1)*(#4)+(#2)*(#5)+(#3)*(#6)}  
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{scalarproduct}{2}{% scalar product of two 3-vectors
    \begingroup%
    \pgfmathparse{\spaux#1#2}%
    \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}  
% projections
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{xcomp3}{3}{% x component of a 3-vector
\begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{#1}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{ycomp3}{3}{% y component of a 3-vector
\begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}  
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{zcomp3}{3}{% z component of a 3-vector
\begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{#3}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
% allows us to do linear combinations
\def\lincomb#1=#2*#3+#4*#5;{%
\path[overlay] let \p1=#3,\p2=#5 in 
({(#2)*(xcomp3\coord1)+(#4)*(xcomp3\coord2)},%
 {(#2)*(ycomp3\coord1)+(#4)*(ycomp3\coord2)},%
 {(#2)*(zcomp3\coord1)+(#4)*(zcomp3\coord2)}) coordinate #1;}
% vector product
\def\vecprod#1=#2x#3;{%
\path[overlay] let \p1=#2,\p2=#3 in 
 ({vpx({\coord1},{\coord2})},%
 {vpy({\coord1},{\coord2})},%
 {vpz({\coord1},{\coord2})}) coordinate #1;}
% vector product auxiliary functions
\newcommand{\vpauxx}[6]{(#2)*(#6)-(#3)*(#5)}     
\newcommand{\vpauxy}[6]{(#4)*(#3)-(#1)*(#6)}
\newcommand{\vpauxz}[6]{(#1)*(#5)-(#2)*(#4)}
% vector product pgf functions
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vpx}{2}{% x component of vector product
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{\vpauxx#1#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vpy}{2}{% y component of vector product
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{\vpauxy#1#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\pgfmathdeclarefunction{vpz}{2}{% z component of vector product
  \begingroup%
  \pgfmathparse{\vpauxz#1#2}%
  \pgfmathsmuggle\pgfmathresult\endgroup}
\begin{document}
 \tdplotsetmaincoords{70}{70}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2,tdplot_main_coords,declare function={R=2;r=sqrt(3);
        alpha1(\th,\ph,\b)=\ph+asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        alpha2(\th,\ph,\b)=-180+\ph-asin(cot(\th)*tan(\b));%
        beta1(\th,\ph,\a)=90+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
        beta2(\th,\ph,\a)=270+atan(cot(\th)/sin(\a-\ph));%
    }]
    \path (0,0,0) coordinate (O)
        (-3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (A)
         (3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (B)
        (0, {sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (C)
        (-3/2, {-(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 2) coordinate (S)
          (0,0,0)  coordinate (I)
       (0, 0,1)  coordinate (T)
       (0,0,1) coordinate(Z)
      (3/2, {(1/2)*sqrt(3)}, 0)  coordinate (D);
    \begin{scope}[tdplot_screen_coords, on background layer]
    \draw[thick] (T) circle (R);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[canvas is xy plane at z={0}]
    \draw[dashed] (O) circle (r);
    \scalprod\myz=(T).(Z); % z component of T
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myel}{atan(-1*\myz/r)}
    \draw[thick] ({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) 
    arc({alpha1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}: 
    {alpha2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,{\myel})}:r) ;
    \end{scope}
    \begin{scope}[on background layer]
     \foreach \v/\position in {T/above,O/below,A/below,B/below,C/below,S/right,D/below} {
      \draw[draw =black, fill=black] (\v) circle (1.2/2pt) node [\position=0.2mm] {$\v$};
     }
    \end{scope}
    \draw[dashed] foreach \X in {A,B,C,O} {(\X) -- (S)}; 
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- cycle (A) -- (D) -- (S);
    %
    \lincomb(S-A)=1*(S)+(-1)*(A);
    \lincomb(S-D)=1*(S)+(-1)*(D);
    \vecprod(nSAD)=(S-A)x(S-D);
    \edef\coordn{\RawCoord(nSADnormalized)}%
    \scalprod\myn=(nSAD).(nSAD);
    \lincomb(nSADnormalized)=(1/sqrt(\myn))*(nSAD)+0*(nSAD);    
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{xcomp3\coordn}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{ycomp3\coordn}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myz}{zcomp3\coordn}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\myang}{-1*atan2(\myy,\myx)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybone}{-90+beta1(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,\myang)}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\mybtwo}{-90+beta2(\tdplotmaintheta,\tdplotmainphi,\myang)}
    \draw[shift={(T)},dashed,red] plot[variable=\t,domain=0:360,smooth] 
    (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,longitude=\myang,latitude=\t);
    \draw[shift={(T)},thick,red] plot[variable=\t,domain=\mybone:\mybtwo,smooth] 
    (xyz spherical cs:radius=R,longitude=\myang,latitude=\t);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The code is reduced very nice.

Comment: @Schrödinger's cat, I added the link. I am sorry about that
 .

Comment: @ThuyNguyen Thanks and no worries!

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat I saw two points `T` and `Z` has the same coordinates.

Comment: @minhthien_2016 Yes, good catch! (It is not wrong, though.)

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Please explain for me the lines `\scalprod\myn=(nSAD).(nSAD);
    \lincomb(nSADnormalized)=(1/sqrt(\myn))*(nSAD)+0*(nSAD);  `

Comment: @minthien_2016 This is a trick to compute the *normalized* normal vector. Why is this so complicated? Because, as of now, the parsing is, admittedly, a bit clumsy and the only two vector operations which are implemented are the linear combination and the vector product.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98393/discussion-between-minhthien-2016-and-schrodingers-cat).

Comment: @minhthien_2016 See [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98348/room-for-minhthien-2016-and-schrodingers-cat).