# How to shade overlaps of multiple circles?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shading, shapes, overlap

I am trying to create in tikz an image like this illustration of the winset of the Q in two-dimensional space (drawn in Inkscape).

[image]

The code below draws the circles as nodes, since that seems to be the easiest way to ensure they all go through the same arbitrary point Q (I am not for present purposes concerned about the labels for the circles) and comes close to what I want, but I would prefer a) no shading at all in the non-overlapping sections and b) darker shading in the overlapping sections.  Any suggestions?

```
    \documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows.meta,patterns,decorations.markings,shapes,shapes.misc,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{through,intersections}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{adjustbox}{max totalsize={\textwidth}{.9\textheight},center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (q) [label=below:{Q},circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt] at (0,0) {\large\textbullet};
\node (a) [label=below:{A},circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt] at (3.5,3) {\large\textbullet};
\node (b)  [label=below:{B},circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt] at (-5.5,1) {\large\textbullet};
\node (c) [label=below:{C},circle,fill=black,inner sep=0pt,minimum size=1pt] at (1,-4.5) {\large\textbullet};
\begin{scope}[blend group=color burn]
\begin{scope}[blend group=multiply]
\node [draw,thick, fill=lightgray,fill opacity=.1] at (a) [circle through={(q)}] {};
\node [draw,thick, fill=lightgray,fill opacity=.1] at (b) [circle through={(q)}] {};
\node [draw,thick ,fill=lightgray,fill opacity=.1] at (c) [circle through={(q)}] {};
\end{scope}
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{adjustbox}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Use circle A to \clip and use circle B to \filldraw

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228593/draw-ellipses-with-different-coloring-for-their-intersection-in-tikz

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!! I'd also use `\clip`s and perhaps this could be a start: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614043/how-to-draw-diagram-of-circles-and-curves-with-pattern-filled-intersections-usi.

Answer (score 2):

This is a way to do it. I changed the circles, placing the centers around Q with polar coordinates so I know beforehand the radii of the circles. But you can do the `\clip`s for the shaded parts also with your circles in the same way.

```
\documentclass[border=2mm,tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
\def\ra{1.5} % radius, circle A
\def\rb{1.6} % radius, circle B
\def\rc{1.4} % radius, circle C
% coordinates
\coordinate (Q) at (0,0);
\coordinate (A) at (150:\ra);
\coordinate (B) at (45:\rb);
\coordinate (C) at (-65:\rc);
% clips
\begin{scope}[gray!50]
  \clip (A) circle (\ra);
  \fill (B) circle (\rb);
  \fill (C) circle (\rc);
\end{scope}
\begin{scope}[gray!50]
  \clip (B) circle (\rb);
  \fill (C) circle (\rc);
\end{scope}
% circles and centers
\foreach\c/\r/\a in {A/\ra/110, B/\rb/135, C/\rc/180} % center/radius/angle for the label
{%
  \draw (\c) circle (\r);
  \fill (\c) circle (0.025) node [above] {$\c$};
  \node at ($(\c)+(\a:\r+0.25)$) {$I_\c(Q)$};
}
\fill (Q) circle (0.025) node [below] {$Q$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]