# draw paraboloid and contour curve

Tags: contour

I want to draw the following graph, especially the contour curve what is black line on the surface of the paraboloid

[image]

my MWE is as follows

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[xmin=0, xmax=3, ymin=0, ymax=2, zmin=0, zmax=10, axis lines=center, view={135}{15},
              xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$, zlabel=$z$, xtick=\empty, ytick=\empty, ztick=\empty]
    \addplot3 [surf, draw=none, opacity=0.5, fill opacity=0.3, restrict z to domain=0:6, data cs=polar, domain=0:360, y domain=0:3] (x, y, 2*y^2);
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

and I want to hide the mesh as well.

Many thanks

Comment: This post could be a start point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619390/how-can-i-draw-the-surface-fx-y-x2y2-like-my-picture

Comment: @Juan, I am going to try, thanks a lot