Surface of revolution around x-axis
How is it possible to get this picture in tikz/Latex. Rightnow I have the following code.

I want to rotate a function around x-axis.
Her is my code.
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
    

    
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=3cm,y=3cm,font=\footnotesize]
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\fill[blue!20] plot[domain=0:1,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)})--(1,0)--(0,0);
\draw[fill=gray!50] (1,0) circle [x radius=.1,y radius=1];

\draw[->] (-0.25,0)--(1.25,0) node[right]{$x$};
\draw[->] (0,-1.25)--(0,1.25) node[above]{$y$};
\draw[-] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{sqrt(\x)}) node[above right]{$f(x)=\sqrt{x}$};;
\draw[->] plot [domain=0:1.25,samples=200] (\x,{-sqrt(\x)}) ;
\draw (0,0) node[below left]{$0$};
\draw (1,3pt)--(1,-3pt) node[below]{$1$};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Have a look here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/621673/140722

I have seen that but how to get the same quality as shown in picture with lighting effect.

did you run the code on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/ and see its quality with the default light effect? Another figure for your reference here https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/619398/140722

Here is a simple Asymptote code (see this link for use 3D Asymptote figure inside LaTeX):

// run on http://asymptote.ualberta.ca/
unitsize(1cm);
size(8cm);
import graph3;
currentprojection=orthographic(3,3,1.2,zoom=.95);
//currentlight=Headlamp;
currentlight.background=.3yellow+.7white;
pen my_spen=Cyan;
pen my_axpen=black+1pt;

// the paraboloid z=f(x,y)= x^2+y^2
real a=1.7; // below z=a^2
triple f(pair M) {
real x = a*(M.x)*cos(M.y);
real y = a*(M.x)*sin(M.y);
return (x,y,x^2+y^2);
}
real rmax=1, rmin=0;
real phimax=2*pi, phimin=0;
surface sf=surface(f, (rmin,phimin), (rmax,phimax), Spline);
draw(sf,surfacepen=my_spen+opacity(.9));
label("$z=x^2+y^2$",f((1,pi)),NE);
draw(Label("$x$",EndPoint),-(a+.5)*X--(a+.5)*X,my_axpen,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$y$",EndPoint),-(a+.5)*Y--(a+.5)*Y,my_axpen,Arrow3());
draw(Label("$z$",EndPoint),-.5Z--(a*a+1)*Z,my_axpen,Arrow3());

