# TiKz Path Exclusion - Compound Shapes (pathfinder functionality)

Tags: tikz-pgf, paths, fill, path-clipping, clip

On Adobe Illustrator, it is very easy to use Pathfinder to create compound shapes by (using the path exclude function with the shape to be retained in the back layer and all paths to be removed in above layers):

[image]

Clearly, we can use a basic application of clipping in an attempt to recreate this with Tikz, which works fine if we are not concerned with drawing borders:

[image]

```
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

%   \clip (0,0) circle (1);

    \fill[red!20] (0,0) circle (1);

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-60]
        \fill[white] (0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-120]
        \fill[white] (0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
    \end{scope}

    \fill[white] (-1.5,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

However, if we **are concerned with draw borders**, it then becomes a lot more interesting and cannot achieve the desired solution easily. Best attempt with a heap of issues (accounting for the line width on the clip (currently it cuts into the line) and overlapping lines from the excluded regions).

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz, border = 1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

    \clip (0,0) circle (1);

    \filldraw[fill=red!10,draw=blue] (0,0) circle (1);

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-60]
        \filldraw[anchor=east,fill=white,draw=blue] (0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
    \end{scope}

    \begin{scope}[rotate=-120]
        \filldraw[anchor=east,fill=white,draw=blue] (0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
    \end{scope}

    \filldraw[fill=white,draw=blue] (-1.5,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way for us to achieve the desired result (first image, second circle with excluded regions but draw available) but with TikZ? Can we maybe do this by clipping a path, then filling that path, but also having that path available to draw?

Comment: I guess a solution is to use TikZ to compute the coordinate of the intersection points, but that one isn't particularly easy to implement.

Comment: Agreed, very difficult to deploy at scale

Comment: Alternatively use whatever tool that can compute the coordinate and then export to TikZ. TeX is not meant to be a programming language that you can program in after all...

Comment: @user202729 wait, I'm using TeX wrong all the time! :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `spath3` library is very powerful and well suited to this question. But in this particular case, we can get a similar result by cheating with a double line like this:

```tex
\documentclass[tikz,border=7pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \clip[postaction={fill=red!20, draw=blue, thick}]
      (0,0) circle (1cm)
    ;
    \path[draw=blue, double, double distance=2mm]
      (-2,0) -- (2,0)
      (0,0) -- (-60:2)
      (0,0) -- (-120:2)
    ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Lovely solution! It's good to know about shortcuts for special cases since the general case can often be a bit time consuming.

Comment: What a lovely solution - well done

Answer (score 7):

Here is a possibility using the `spath3` Ti*k*Z library and following the steps from Andrew Stacey's excellent answer [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/614043/how-to-draw-diagram-of-circles-and-curves-with-pattern-filled-intersections-usi/614225#614225). The code is not so short but is repetitive and easy to understand (I hope). We need to create the paths (circle and rectangles), split them at the intersections and then use the appropriate components to draw the desired figure

Something like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,spath3}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round]
  \useasboundingbox (-1.2,-1.2) rectangle (1.2,1.2);
  % original paths, not drawn
  \path[spath/save=circle]            (0,0)    circle (1);
  \path[rotate=240,spath/save=rect24] (0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
  \path[rotate=300,spath/save=rect30] (0,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
  \path[spath/save=rect00]         (-1.5,-0.1) rectangle (1.5,0.1);
  % spath3 operations
  \tikzset
  {% Circles have an "empty" component at the start which
   % moves from the centre to the rim; it can be irritating
   % when trying to count components later so this removes
   % any empty components
     spath/remove empty components={circle},
   % Now split each path where it intersects with the lines
     spath/split at intersections={circle}{rect00},
     spath/split at intersections={circle}{rect24},
     spath/split at intersections={circle}{rect30},
     spath/split at intersections={rect00}{rect24},
     spath/split at intersections={rect00}{rect30},
     spath/split at intersections={rect24}{rect30},
   % Each path is now a collection of components; to work
   % with them individually we split them into a list of
   % separate paths which is stored in a macro
     spath/get components of={circle}\Ccpts,
     spath/get components of={rect00}\Rcpts,
     spath/get components of={rect24}\Scpts,
     spath/get components of={rect30}\Tcpts,
  }
  \draw[fill=red!10,draw=blue,
        spath/use=\getComponentOf\Ccpts{1},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf\Rcpts{2},weld}
       ];
  \draw[fill=red!10,draw=blue,
        spath/use=\getComponentOf\Ccpts{3},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf\Scpts{3},weld},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf\Rcpts{8},weld},
       ];
  \draw[fill=red!10,draw=blue,
        spath/use=\getComponentOf\Ccpts{5},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf\Tcpts{3},weld},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf\Scpts{7},weld}
       ];
  \draw[fill=red!10,draw=blue,
        spath/use=\getComponentOf\Ccpts{7},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf\Rcpts{4},weld},
        spath/use={\getComponentOf\Tcpts{7},weld}
       ];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Remark:** the last (straight) line of each sector could be drawn with the `cycle` option, but I did it this way to see the `spath3` library working.

Comment: Fabulous! And some more characters to get over the minimum character limit.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, thanks!!! But the merit is all yours :-D

Comment: @AndrewStacey Being Fabulous...hence +1. :-)

Comment: @Sebastiano, thanks too!!

Comment: Wow, that is a beautiful solution. Well done and thank you!

Comment: @AndrewStacey, I'm sorry about your name :(

Comment: @JuanCastaño Don't worry about it! As a spider-fan I've considered changing it to that anyway.